# Suggestions on picking up colors

Tags: gui-design, design

I've designed a website and it looks as below.

[image]

I'm a developer did this design work since the designer not available for couple of days.

I need suggestions on the below.
**Note** The orange background should be there.

1. There is a chat window to right, what would be better color to be used in the place where the user types, and what can be optimal color for the chat window background with the page background as orange.
2. What colors, fonts, shapes and sizes should I use in the chat bubbles, it should also differentiate the user message(smiley) from the reply message(robot image)
3. how to have a better look of those icons in chat window.
4. what can be best background for the green back-grounded text at the bottom.

I know that this is a lot, but I've to see this chat window par from the other components in this webpage.

Thanks

Comment: are orange & green color mandatory? I think you should have edges slightly curved not much curvy. Border-radius: 2px; would be ideal. May be you could use subtle background image. Are you planning to keep same layout or can it be changed?

Comment: Hi @NB4, thanks for the quick reply the orange is mandatory, but not the green.

Comment: How about layout?

Comment: @NB4, sorry for the delayed email. It would be very helpful if you can suggest some... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Choosing colors**
As for choosing colors I would like to point you to [ColorSupplyyy's app](http://colorsupplyyy.com/app/). It uses well known standards for choosing the right color combinations. Go through the different color harmonies and see what goes best with orange. (See your not that wrong with orange when going for a triad color harmony)

When choosing the right color for the chat window, keep contrast in mind. (Keep that in mind for the entire page).
You can read more about the importance of contrast [here](https://accessibility.blog.gov.uk/2016/06/17/colour-contrast-why-does-it-matter/). They even offer a great [tool](https://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastanalyser/) with which you can check if the contrast passes official accessibility guidelines. I think you might want to look at the contrast of the white letters on the orange background. You might find out that it might not be that legible.

My personal opinion on the chat window is that it should have a white background. Else, the orange would be too much. You can reapply the orange color in the chat bubbles.

---

**Choosing fonts**
A good legible base size for fonts is 16 pixels. You can deviate from it based on what looks good, but try and keep it legible (not too small). When choosing what font, use a serif or a sans-serif font. Don't go overboard with fancy lettering for body copy. This is okay for short titles, but a "normal" font will be easier to read.
You'll still have plenty of choices. But perhaps you client already has a certain font they use, if not on the web, perhaps in print or in email. Keeping things uniform will help with [brand recognition](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/brand-recognition.asp).

---

**Inspiration**
When you feel stuck, it helps too look at what top notch designers do. Get inspiration and even steal small bits to apply to your own design.

> "Good artists copy, great artists steal." - Pablo Picasso

[Dribbble](https://www.dribbble.com) is a great source for inspiration.
[You can search by color](https://dribbble.com/colors/FEA500?percent=30) to see what other people did with your color orange for example.
You can also get inspiration on [chat windows](https://dribbble.com/search?q=chat).

One last personal note: I'm wondering what the relation is between the girl and the robot. I assume the chat window is empty when you reach this page, so you don't see any responses yet with the robot avatar. My assumption would be that I would be asking my questions to this digital, young girl. But instead, a robot is answering my questions. My suggestion would be to use both robot or girl in both places.

Good luck.

Comment: Interesting tool you have suggested. +1 Even I agree on your last point.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Make the chat window a very light grey and the text field completely white. This will separate it from the rest of the page and also to make it easier on the eyes and cleaner.
2. The chat bubbles should be coloured like this: white for the message sent by  the user, orange for the reply. It makes the response easy to find. A vibrant colour will drag the eyes of the viewer to that point.
3. The icons in the chat window should be flat and simple, making them more legible and better looking. Making the icons simple will make the page more modern and legible.
4. I would recommend using a very dark grey for the footer. It will separate it from the rest of the page without making in too noticeable.

Comment: I believe your answer would be more helpful if you provide any context as to why he should use the colours you suggest. ["Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Alright. I would make the chat window white to separate it from the rest of the page and also to make it easier on the eyes and cleaner. I would colour the chat bubbles that way to make the response easy to find. A vibrant colour will drag the eyes of the viewer to that point. Making the icons simple will make the page more modern and legible while a dark grey colour for the footer will separate it from the rest of the page without making in too noticeable.